# Why is my php code bypassing a few if statements?

Tags: php, if-statement

As I was working with my program, I had come up with an unknown error. What happens is that my code is bypassing two `if` statements. Here's my code:

```
<?
session_start();
if ($_POST){
  $ao = trim($_POST['amountof']);
  $continue = true;
  if (strlen($ao) < 1){  ####First If-Statement Bypassed####
    $continue = false;
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Please enter in a value!";
  }
  if (strlen($ao) > 20){  ####Second If-Statement Bypassed####
    $continue = false;
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Your value has exceeded 20!";
  }
  if (!is_numeric($ao)){
    $continue = false;
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Value is not numeric!";
  }
}

?>
<form method="post">
<?
if (isset($_SESSION['error'])){
  print "<span style=\"color: red; font-weight: bold;\">" . $_SESSION['error'] . "                </span><br />";
}
?>
How many letters are you planning to process?<br />
<span style="font-size:.8em; color: grey;">You may not exceed 20</span><br />
<input type="text" name="amountof" style="width:25px;" maxlength="2"/>
<input type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>

<? unset($_SESSION['error']); ?>
```

The if statements that are bypassed are marked in the code.
Thank you!

Comment: So what are the contents of `$ao` and `$_POST['amountof']`?

Comment: try to `echo $ao;` and see it's value

Comment: Can you show sample data submitted as $_POST['amountof'] for which your code does not work as expected? Also, does the third check operate as expected, or none of them?

Comment: Are you sure they're actually being bypassed? The variables you set inside those ifs are the same ones you set in the last if, so unless you provide an invalid value still which passes the is_numeric test, you'll never be able to see whether or not those ifs are actually run - their effects are hidden by that last if.

Comment: `$ao` doesnt show anything when the form is submitted with no value in the text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
<?php

 session_start();
 $_SESSION['error']='';

  if (isset($_POST['amountof'])){
  $ao = trim($_POST['amountof']);
  $continue = true;
  if (strlen($ao) < 1){ 
    $continue = false;
    $_SESSION['error'].= "Please enter in a value!<br/>";
  }

  if (!is_numeric($ao)){
    $continue = false;
    $_SESSION['error'].= "Value is not numeric!<br/>";
  }
  elseif ($ao > 20){ 
    $continue = false;
    $_SESSION['error'].= "Your value has exceeded 20!";
  }
}
?>
<form method="post">
<?php
 if (!empty($_SESSION['error'])){

 //......
```

or simplified(note that the user may type negative values or 0 what currently will pass the test)

```
if (!is_numeric($ao) || $ao<1 || $ao>20){
        $continue = false;
        $_SESSION['error']= "Please enter in a numeric value between 1 and 20";
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing some sample data, I believe you are simply overwriting the error variable, not bypassing the if statements. Let's run through the code with the case where nothing is entered.

The code inside the first if statement runs, since the strlen($ao) would be less than one. $_SESSION['error'] would be "Please enter in a value!"

Now the code in the second if statement doesn't run, since strlen($ao) is obviously not over 20.

The code in the third if statement runs, since an empty string is not numeric. Since you are overwriting $_SESSION['error'], the variable would simply be "Value is not numeric!". Thus it would appear the first if statement is bypassed.

Try concatenating the error string instead of overwriting.

EDIT: By using the code snippet posted by Dr Molle just before I answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
```

on line two, instead of what you're using, because `$_POST` behaves like an array.

Comment: $_POST is always set, when no POST-data has been send, it's an empty array, what will be evaluated as false.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it doesn't seem to help with the problem